# Como percorrer um dataGridView e armazenar os valores numa List ou Array

Tags: c#

Tenho que inserir alguns dados numa `datagridView` e em seguida preciso recuperar esses valores e armazenar numa `List` ou `Array`, para que em seguida eu possa enviar para o banco de dados. 
Pessoal, não sei como fazer isso! se os Srs. puderem me ajudar, ficarei agradecido!

Segue um trecho do código que estou testando, sem sucesso..

Obs. Já consigo inserir os dados com esse código abaixo:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
        //Informo os nomes das colunas do dataGridView
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Nome";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "E-mail";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Telefone";
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
        //limpo os controles
        textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox2.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox3.Text = String.Empty;
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
           ??
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saudações.

Você pode usar o `for` no lugar do `foreach` para percorrer o `DataGridView` e pegar os dados através dos índices das células de cada linha.

```
//percorre o DataGridView
   for (Int32 i = 0; i < dgwMeuDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
          meuList.add = dgwMeuDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();// coluna 1
          meuList.add = dgwMeuDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();// coluna 2
          meuList.add = dgwMeuDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();// coluna 3
      }
```

Comment: Olá Agnaldo! Fiz como vc sugeriu, e pós percorrer pelo dataGridView o programa retorna o seguinte erro: System.NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to instance of an object.'
 System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null

Comment: Opa, Beleza?  O erro ocorre porque da forma que você está preebchendo o DataGridView a útima linha dele fica sempre vazia e ao tentar adicionar esta linha vazia ao seu List realmente dará erro. Uma solução é: 
<pre> for (Int32 i = 0; i < dgwMeuDataGridView.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{...}</pre>

Coloquei apenas um menos 1 para não ler a última linha do DataGridView.

Comment: for (Int32 i = 0; i < dgwMeuDataGridView.Rows.Count -1; i++)

Comment: Claro que se de alguma forma uma linha do DataGridView ficar vazia vai gerar erro ao capturar esta linha vazia para seu List. O ideal é fazer validação para não pegar linha com conteúdo vazio ou não permitir nenhuma linha vazia ao preencher o DataGridView. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: sim , sim.. depois quando deparei com esse erro eu pesquisei mais um pouco e achei exatamente o que você disse ai.. Obrigado mais uma vez @Agnaldo

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado. se foi útil marque como resposta para ranquear e ajudar as outras pessoas que estiverem com esta mesma duvida, abraço

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro de tudo você tem que criar uma estrutura elementar para receber os seus dados. Nesse exemplo eu criei uma `struct` chamada `Individuo`que contém três campos `nome`, `email` e `telefone`. Para essa `struct` também criei um `constructor` que aceita três argumentos e que com esses argumentos preenche os campos da estrutura de dados.

Logo em seguida declarei uma lista chamada `Contato` lista essa cujo a finalidade é receber os dados do seu componente `dataGridView1`.

Lá no final eu modifiquei o seu método `Button2_Click`adicionando código para para preencher a lista de `Contatos` com as informações de cada `Individuo` com as informações obtidas de seu `dataGridView1`:

```
//Estrutura que modela um único individuo
private struct Individuo
{
   String nome;
   String email;
   String telefone;

   public Individuo(String _nome, String _email, String _telefone)
   {
      nome = _nome;
      email = _email;
      telefone = _telefone;
   }
}

//Lista que receberá os dados
List<Individuo> Contatos= new List<Individuo>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
    //Informo os nomes das colunas do dataGridView
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Nome";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "E-mail";
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Telefone";
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
    //limpo os controles
    textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
    textBox2.Text = String.Empty;
    textBox3.Text = String.Empty;
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Código para preencher a lista de Contatos com as informações de cada Individuo com as informações obtidas de seu dataGridView1
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
       Contatos.Add(
           new Individuo(dataGridViewRow.Cells["Nome"].Value.ToString(), 
                         dataGridViewRow.Cells["E-mail"].Value.ToString(), 
                         dataGridViewRow.Cells["Telefone"].Value.ToString()
                         )
                    );  
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom!! Fiz os testes e  funcionou!! Obrigado Augusto!
Augusto, você poderia explicar como eu posso pegar esses valores que estão nas variáveis do indivíduo para passar ao banco..
Geralmente eu faço da seguinte forma:
string resp = "";
resp = NContato.Inserir(_nome, _email, _telefone);

......// mas não estou conseguindo!

Comment: @Phil: Não sei se é bem isso que você pediu mas deve ser algo como :`foreach (Individuo ind in Contatos) { resp = NContato.Inserir(ind.nome, ind.email, ind.telefone); }`

Comment: Fiz como vc sugeriu, mas ele ainda não enxerga as variáveis nome, email e telefone... Vou continuar pesquisando aqui! Obrigado @Augusto

Comment: Boa pesquisa, mas qualquer coisa abra uma pergunta especifica sobre banco de dados mostrando o código dentro de `NContato.Inserir`.

Comment: NContato é uma classe com o método inserir, que no caso é para receber os valores dessas variáveis nome, email.... 
Valeu @Augusto!!